# How can I interpret the results of a simulation of ARX process in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, simulation, differential-equations

I simulated the the following commands:

```
process_arx= idpoly([1 -0.5],[0 0 0.6 -0.2],1,1,1,'NoiseVariance',0.05,'Ts',1);
uk=idinput(2555,'prbs',[0 0.2], [-1 1]);
yk=sim(process_arx,uk,'Noise');
```

And the first 10 of uk and yk are:

```
[uk(1:10) yk(1:10)]

ans =

   -1.0000    0.1202
   -1.0000    0.4702
   -1.0000   -0.8700
   -1.0000   -0.6422
   -1.0000   -0.6498
   -1.0000   -1.0173
   -1.0000   -1.0056
   -1.0000   -0.8262
   -1.0000   -0.0129
   -1.0000    0.2128
```

As far as I understand what I am doing is simulating the following equation:

```
y(t)= 0.5*y(t-1) + 0.6*u(t-2) -0.2*u(t-3)
```

So for example, if I want y(4), I have to calculate  : `y(4)=0.5*y(3) + 0.6*u(2) -0.2*u(1)`

From the values : y(3)= -0.87 ; u(2)= -1 and u(1) = -1

y(4) should be -0.835 and the simulation gave me  -0.6422 !

How can I interpret correctly the simulation result?

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't take into account that the model innovations e(t) are stochastic, i.e.

```
y(t)= 0.5*y(t-1) + 0.6*u(t-2) -0.2*u(t-3) + e(t)
```

Comment: You are correct! I run the simulation again without noise and everything worked as I was expecting!